# NodeJS SQL Server - How to query with array input parameters that would return one promise

Tags: node.js, sql-server, promise

In my SQL server, I have two columns col1, and col2 belonging in two separate tables table1 and table2 respectively, i.e., col1 is accessible in table1 and col2 accessibile in table2.

I have arrays defined in my NodeJS code as:

```
let columnsArray = ['col1', 'col2'];
let tablesArray = ['table1', 'table2'];
```

I want to be able to query both the columns belonging in different tables.

```
}).then(result => {
   // some code

   // HELP Required
   for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
     return pool.request()
     .query("SELECT " + COL[i] + " FROM " + TABLE[i]) // returns a promise
   } 
}).then(result = {
   console.log(result.recordsets)
})
```

I'm using the NPM Module [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql). I'm new to the concept of promises, wondering this where my code might be failing.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by adding what I think is a more useful array, one that combines columns and tables in a single object for each "pair"

```
let columnsArray = ['col1', 'col2'];
let tablesArray = ['table1', 'table2'];

let tabColArray = tablesArray.map((table, i) => ({table, col: columnsArray[i]}));
```

The above code results in a array that looks like the following, to be honest, I'd just create tabColArray like this and be done with it

```
let tabColArray = [
    {table: 'table1', col: 'col1'},
    {table: 'table2', col: 'col2'}
];
```

Either way - your code is now

```
}).then(result => {
    // some code

    // HELP Required
    return Promise.all(tabColArray.map(({table, col}) => pool.request().query(`SELECT ${col} FROM ${table}`)));

}).then(results => { // results is an array, one for each query
    results.forEach(result => {
        console.log(result.recordsets);
    });
});
```